# Tensorflow: graph building dependent on evaluation

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am writing a tensorflow graph of the following format:

```
def process_label(label):
    return some_operation(label.eval())

Input: X, Label
output,state = NN_Layers()
processed_output = process_data(output)
processed_label = process_label(processed_output, Label)
loss = cross_entropy(processed_output, processed_label)
optimize = GradientDescentOptimizer.minimize(loss)

Session.run(optimize, feed_dict{X:input, Label:label})
```

The problem with this model is that I need the values of output in order to process my label the way I want it so I can calculate the loss. If I try to use output.eval(session) here, it will not work, because my session will execute the whole graph and therefore I can only call it in the end.

I wonder if there`s a way I can break this graph apart in two and still have the gradient descent work through the network, or if there`s any other way to do this.

Comment: If you want to calculate the loss value and run gradient descent at the same time, you can just do `_, loss_value = session.run([optimize, loss], feed_dict=...)`.

Comment: I am sorry, I was not really clear. In order to calculate the loss I need to have the processed_label value, and in process_label() I need to do calculations with the value of the tensors, and therefore use Tensor.eval(). I was not able to build the entire graph since it depends on this evaluation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a flaw in these, but here are two ideas to start with: 1) easy vs. 2) efficient:

1) Put it all in one graph, as though you have the labels you want. Execute once to get the outputs (only feeding the placeholders required for outputs, tensorflow won't require the labels placeholder for this). Then run the training op, feeding the labels placeholder and again the placeholders needed for the outputs. It will re-run all of the ops to calculate "outputs", so not efficient.

2) Do it with two separate graphs (two sessions might be necessary as well?). Compute the outputs and the gradient of the outputs with respect to the trainable variables (tf.gradients) in graph 1, compute your labels as needed, compute gradients of the loss with respect to outputs in graph 2 (tf.gradients) (outputs are a placeholder in graph 2), multiply the gradients to get the gradient of the loss with respect to the variables, and optizer.apply_gradients() in graph 1.

Edit: actually, you can use one graph in option 2. You can feed output directly back in for the output tensor when you go to calculate d_loss/d_output, shortcutting the operations to calculate output. i.e. feed_dict is not limited to placeholders.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely go for the second option, that`s what I was looking for, I just did not enough math, it`s all chain rule, right? Thanks once again.

Comment: yes, chain rule. `dloss/dvariable_i = sum_j dloss/doutput_j*doutput_j/dvariable_i`. Also, looking closer at `tf.gradients()`, you will need a `tf.gradients()` operation for each `output_j`. `tf.gradients()` seems to sum up all `dvariable_i's` across supplied outputs, but you need them separate to do the multiplication above. Lastly, since the graphs are the same, aside from the addition of gradients, it might be easiest to start with 1) and move on to 2) when you want to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`py_func`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ecc6c5ae3dcec7ea263a010ae2b6b1f7dc0da1a8/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard0/tf.py_func.md) to wrap any computation as a tensorflow op. That will not work well in distributed settings, but it'll allow you to put arbitrary computation into a tensorflow graph.

Unless you're doing something very complicated in the `process_*` functions, you should write them in tensorflow ops. Most of the time that's easier than you think. If there's specific functionality missing, file a feature request.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I can wrap a couple of functions, but there are others that use certain libraries and it would be extremely complicated, if possible at all, to do this. Also I plan to use this in a distributed setting. Is there any other way you can think of?